# proving bijectivity of function mapping from powerset to powerset

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let S be a set and consider f: $\mathcal P(S) \mapsto \mathcal P (S)$ with $f(A) = S\backslash A$. Prove f is a bijection

With injectivity, I ended up at $\mathcal P(S) \backslash A_1 = \mathcal P(S) \backslash A_2$, but not sure what to do from here. I know why it's true intuitively, I just not sure what the next step/line is from here.

Answer (score 1):

The injectivity is obvious. You have $f(A)=S-A$. Take $B \in  \mathcal{P}(S)$ then $f((S-B))=S- (S- B)=B$ so it's a bijection.